# Should I turn on firewall,selinux on after cpanel installed?

Tags: firewall

I am running Centos 5.5.

Before start cpanel installation, the installation guide says to disable firewall and selinux, so I did it.

Now cpanel installed, up and running.
Should I turn iptables & selinux on again? Or cpanel has own security tools so that my system no longer needs iptables/selinux?

Keep it on or stop? Kind of confuse, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cPanel will not work properly if you turned on SELINUX because of SELINUX contexts.

You need to turn on IPtables.

But it will be a good idea to manage IPtables using CSF firewall, which is front end for IPtables.

You can install CSF using following:

```
yum -y install perl-libwww-perl && \
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/csf.tgz && \
tar -xzf csf.tgz && \
cd csf && \
sh install.sh
```

Comment: That (the SELinux bit) kinda sounds like poor engineering on the part of cPanel. I'm pretty sure that, with a bit of work, it could be made SELinux friendly.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the firewall CSF, which is the most commonly used firewall along with Cpanel. After installing CSF, a plugin will appear on the WHM.